# Error while calling a method in cluster.js is : Security policy is you must post to get JSON

Tags: javascript, json, google-search-appliance, security-policy

We are getting this error:

> Security policy is you must post to get JSON

This is with some function in cluster.js being called to get JSON results. Can anyone give some hint as to what this error is and what can be the possible solution?

Comment: so what is the exact error? If you are passing data, you can check if your are passing the right data parameters in firebug, and also the return value. Also, try specifying the dataType in your ajax request.

Comment: someone else asked this, in relation to upgrading GSA version:
http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Search-Appliance-Help/browse_thread/thread/67a940e5730858cc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you must do an XHR POST to retrieve the results.

Comment: There is some proxy introduced between somehow. And the error seems to be coming from that I am not sure how is it related.

Comment: So the security policy is not on the server but on the proxy in between? I am a little confused here, i think you need to give a more details about your problem.